# how to get gforth extensions

Tags: gforth

I have some gforth only words such as { } and u>= but not others such as [: ;] and u/
. Should I have these by default or how do I get them? I'm not seeing a file to include. I'm using gforth from the Void Linux repo.

Comment: You got them? I am now searching for them. Any hint would be appreciated